# Need a self-hosted ftp-like solution with notifications of uploads/downloads

Tags: windows, ftp, file-sharing, notifications, local-storage

I have been searching and searching for the perfect solution to our needs and have yet to find one, paid or free.

We currently use software called [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/) on a Windows box and it is all but perfect.
It's self-hosted which means there are no limits on storage.
There is no user limit.
There is no share limit.
We can share ANYTHING on our network.  Though we only share out of one folder for security reasons.
Permissions revolve around the shares.  So I can create a user and give that user access to several shares with different permissions.  View this share, upload and download to that share, full admin rights on another share.  The user only has one username and password combo to keep track of and we control exactly what they can and can't do.

The big missing feature is notifications and tracking.  We have no way of knowing if files have been uploaded or downloaded unless the user sends us an email or we just randomly check.
What we'd like to have is a solution that has all the features above, but would also give us full user tracking.  When they logged on and what they did while logged on.

Does anyone know of anything like this?  I can't believe no one has a product like this.  In fact, I've even looked into cloud-based solutions and they don't even have full user tracking.  I swear if I had the time I'd write the software myself! :-)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Questions asking for product suggestions are not on topic for ANY Stack Exchange website.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CrushFTP.  It can run on a number of platforms and is very reasonably priced.  Support is great and it is very feature rich.  There is a free trial available and support is good even during trial.

The system will sent alerts based on a number of criteria like an upload or download.  It has so many features you will likley need to test for some time to explore all options.

[CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com)